# WPF Multicolumn Combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, multiple-columns

I have the following data template used for a multicolumn combo box:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ShipViaKey">
    <Grid Height="23" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Code}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Carrier}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The combo box is defined like this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CboShipVia" SelectedValue="{Binding FkCarrier, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="PkCarrier" IsEnabled="{Binding HasData}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShipViaKey}"/>
```

This is all fine; except I want to only display the "Code" of the selected item in the combo box, not both values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `ItemTemplate`, use `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="23" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Carrier}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also, set `DisplayMemberPath` to `Code` property.

Comment: Now I'm back to where I started. This was my original solution...but I cannot get the selected item to be highlighted when the combo is dropped down. Using the solution in my question highlights the selected row...but displays the entire template in the control. I want a combination of the two.

Comment: Actually...after comparing yours to my original, there were a couple of minor differences. I was using <Setter Property="Template"> and <ContentTemplate>. Your sample has <Setter Proper="ContentTemplate"> and <DataTemplate>. When I made those changes it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution that provides **columns vertical alignment** thanks to the SharedSizeGroup feature.

Resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="advancedComboxItemDataTemplate">
    <Grid Width="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="advancedComboxItemsPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" IsItemsHost="True"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Usage:

```
<ComboBox Width="300"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReferentialData.BankReferences}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject.PayTermBankReference}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource advancedComboxItemDataTemplate}"
          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource advancedComboxItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
```