# How to bind the whole object instead of just a property to controls of a combobox-list in C#/WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have this xaml code:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="598,0,0,16" x:Name="comboBoxActivityRecordingOrder" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="248" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.t.activityrecordingorder, ElementName=listViewTasks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="comboBoxActivityRecordingOrder_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="23" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- multi column combo box http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893348/wpf-multicolumn-combobox -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding activityrecordingordertype.code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding banumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ***, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ActivityRecordingOrderConverter}}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

In the 3rd column I have to display a string which I can generate with the ActivityRecordingOrderConverter from the whole object. What do I have to put at *** to give the whole object to the Converter? I tried "this", "self", putting nothing. All don't work.

Comment: Nothing, just leave it out, or set [`Path=.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=netframework-4.7.1). And note that all your `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` settings are pointless. They have no effect.

Comment: Yeah I found the {Binding} syntax elsewhere. However, this syntax does not work if you want to add things behind a comma. So the compiler complains about {Binding, Converter... But the Path=. works. Thx

Comment: So don't write the comma: `{Binding Converter=...}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To bind directly to the binding source, you can simply leave the path off.  To be more explicit, you can specify either an empty string or a single dot (`.`).  In the property path syntax, a lone `.` is a special character meaning "the current object".

```
{Binding Path=''}
{Binding Path=.}
{Binding Converter={...}}
```

There is another 'special' path character that's worth knowing: using `/` tells the binding engine to drill into the *current item*  in the preceding collection, where the current item is the one specified by the collection's default `ICollectionView`.  When used on its own, the preceding collection would simply be the binding source itself.

Example:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items/Name}" />
```

Here, binding to `Items/Name` tells the binding engine, "bind to the `Name` of the currently selected item in `Items`.  Setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `true` tells the `ListBox` to synchronize the selected item in the collection view with the selected list box item.  The end result is that the text block shows a property of whatever item is selected in the list.

Comment: Thanks! For `UWP` the `{x:Bind Converter={...}}` works for me.

Comment: Tested in UWP project, it seems only `{x:Bind Path=''}` works now. The editor will give you an error though.